# How can I change the menu item style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Еhis is the hierarchical menu. I would like to change the style of the top level and child menu items. Maybe it is easy, but I didn't find anything on it.

[image]

My XAML:

```
<Menu Name="MainMenu" Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <Menu.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Objects1}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="{Binding ObjectClass}" Width="{Binding ObjectSize}" Foreground="#616161" />
               <Label Content="{Binding ObjectName}" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#616161" FontFamily="Pe-icon-7-stroke"></Label>
         </StackPanel>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Label Content="{Binding ObjectName}" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#616161" FontFamily="Pe-icon-7-stroke"> 
               </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `Menu.ItemContainerStyle` to apply style to set any property on your menu items and similary `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle` to set any style on submenu items.

```
 <Menu Name="MainMenu" Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Menu.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Objects1}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{Binding ObjectName}" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#616161" FontFamily="Pe-icon-7-stroke"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding ObjectName}" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#616161" FontFamily="Pe-icon-7-stroke">
                        </Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
    </Menu>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works for me, but i have one more thing how i overwrite the default style